# Erro ao buscar imagens do banco de dados - PHP

Tags: php

```
As imagens não aparecem na pagina
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php

    $banco = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","bd");
    $sql = "SELECT arquivo FROM lojas";
    $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $album[] = $linha;  
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.php">
</head>
<body>
<header>    

<table>
<tr>
    <?php
        foreach($album as $foto){
    ?>
    <td>
        <img src="<?php echo "./imagens/".$foto["nome"] ?>" width="260" height="200"/>
        <td>
    <?php }
    ?>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A gente teria que ser um `Hacker` para descobrir a estrutura da sua tabela no banco para ver os nomes das colunas e fazer uma correção na declaração `SELECT` ou em `$foto["nome"]` dentro do foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tendo informação suficiente para fazer um diagnóstico como deve ser, primeiro ver se nessa tabela, o nome da imagem está de facto a ser gravada na coluna 'nome'.
Segundo, a query só está a recolher dados da coluna 'arquivo' da tabela loja. Teria de ser:

```
$sql = "SELECT arquivo,nome FROM lojas";
```

Caso contrário, a coluna 'arquivo' é onde estão a ser gravados os nomes dos ficheiros, portanto o php é que está mal, por conseguinte, teríamos:

```
<img src="<?php echo "./imagens/".$foto["arquivo"] ?>" width="260" height="200"/>
```

Comment: Isso resolveu. Obrigado!  <img src="<?php echo "./imagens/".$foto["arquivo"] ?>" width="260" height="200"/>

Comment: De nada. Sempre às ordens :)